# why throttling is needed in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, throttling

I'm sorry if my question is very obvious.
I am looking for the answer to why throttling is needed in WCF.

Is it something that depends on customer requirements, a hardware dependency or something else?

If this is hardware specific then WCF should automatically conclude its values or how can we conclude throttling values based on hardware configuration? is there any user guide for it?

If it's a customer requirement, then why would anyone want to reduce the throughput of their application?

Answer (score 1):

As [explained by Dev Pro](http://devproconnections.com/net-framework/concurrency-and-throttling-configurations-wcf-services):

> However, regardless of the concurrency mode, server resources are not
>   generally capable of servicing an unlimited number of concurrent
>   requests. Each request may require a certain amount of processing,
>   memory allocation, hard disk access, network access, and other
>   overhead.
>
> WCF provides a throttling behavior to manage server load and resource
>   consumption (with the following properties):
>
> - MaxConcurrentCalls. Limits the number of concurrent requests that can be processed by all service instances. The default value is 16.
> - MaxConcurrentInstances. Limits the number of service instances that can be allocated at a given time. For PerCall services, this setting
>     matches the number of concurrent calls. For PerSession services, this
>     setting matches the number of active session instances. This setting
>     doesn t matter for Single instancing mode, because only one instance
>     is ever created. The default value for this setting is 2,147,483,647.
> - MaxConcurrentSessions. Limits the number of active sessions allowed for the service. This includes application sessions, transport
>     sessions (for TCP and named pipes, for example), reliable sessions,
>     and secure sessions. The default value is 10.